# How to extract coordinates to plot line segments connecting legend keys in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I've long puzzled over a concise way to communicate significance of an interaction between numeric and categorical variables in a line plot (response on the Y-axis, numeric predictor variable on the X-axis, and each level of the categoric variable a line of a different color or pattern plotted on those axes). I finally came up with the idea of drawing the traditional "brackets and p-values" connecting legend keys instead of lines of data.

Here is a mockup of what I mean:

```
library(ggplot2);
mydat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:3,function(ii) data.frame(
    y=seq(0,10)*c(.695,.78,1.39)[ii]+c(.322,.663,.847)[ii],
    a=factor(ii-1),b=0:10)));

myplot <- ggplot(data=mydat,aes(x=b,y=y,colour=a,group=a)) +
    geom_line()+theme(legend.position=c(.1,.9));

# Plotting with p-value bracket:
myplot + 
    # The three line segments making up the bracket
    geom_segment(x=1.2,xend=1.2,y=13.8,yend=13) + 
    geom_segment(x=1.1,xend=1.2,y=13,yend=13)  + 
    geom_segment(x=1.1,xend=1.2,y=13.8,yend=13.8) +
    # The text accompanying the bracket. 
    geom_text(label='p < 0.001',x=2,y=13.4);
```

This is less cluttered than trying to plot brackets someplace on the line-plot itself.

The problem is that the x and y values for the `geom_segment`s and `geom_text` were obtained by trial and error and for another dataset these coordinates would be completely wrong. That's a problem if I'm trying to write a function whose purpose is to automate the process of pulling these contrasts out of models and plotting them (kind of like the `effects` package, but with more flexibility about how to represent the data).

My question is: is there a way to somehow pull the actual coordinates of each box comprising the legend and convert them to the scale used by `geom_segment` and `geom_text`, or manually specify the coordinates of each box when creating the `myplot` object, or reliably predict where the individual boxes will be and convert them to the plot's scale given that `myplot$theme$legend.position` returns `0.1 0.9`?

I'd like to do this within ggplot2, because it's robust, elegant, and perfect for all the other things I want to do with my script. I'm open to using additional packages that extend ggplot2 and I'm also open to other approaches to visually indicating significance level on line-plots. However, suggestions that amount to "you shouldn't even do that" are not constructive-- because whether or not I personally agree with you, my collaborators and their editors don't read Stackoverflow (unfortunately).

---

Update:

This question kind of simplifies to: if the `myplot$theme$legend.key.height` is in lines and `myplot$theme$legend.position` seems to be roughly in fractions of the overall plot area (but not exactly) how can I convert these to the units in which the x and y axes are delineated, or alternatively, convert the x and y axis scales to the units of `legend.key.height` and `legend.position`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the answer to your question as posed.  But, another, definitely quickly do-able if less fancy approach to convey the information is to change the names of the levels so that the level names include significance codes. In your first example, you could use

```
levels(mydat$a) <- list("0" = "0", "1 *" = "1", "2 *" = "2")
```

And then the legend will reflect this:

[image]

With more levels and combos of significance, you could probably work out a set of symbols. Then mention in your figure legend the p level reflected in each set of symbols.

This might be a related way to convey the information:  The figure below is produced by `rxnNorm` in `HandyStuff` [here](https://github.com/bryanhanson/HandyStuff).  Unfortunately, this is another non-answer as I have not been able to make this work with the new version of `ggplot2`.  Hopefully I can figure it out soon. 
[image: rxnNorm]

Comment: You're right! Why didn't I think of that? Brackets do still have the advantage of communicating the contrasts used in the model, but if nobody can suggest a way of doing brackets, I'll go with your answer.

Comment: I've done a lot of function writing with `ggplot2` and I have to say it can be challenging at times (don't flame me people!).  Much easier in interactive mode.  Possibly not worth the time, although one can learn a lot.  Someone will have the bracket idea implemention I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not using `ggplot2`, but the `lattice`  package.  I think `dotplot` is what I would use if I want to compare a continuous variable versus categorical variables.

Here I use `dotplot` in 2 manners, one where I reproduce your plot, and another where

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)      ## to get ggplot2 theme

  #y versus levels of B, in different panel of A
  p1 <- dotplot(b~y|a , 
          data = mydat, 
          groups = a,
          type = c("p", "h"),
          main = "interaction between numeric and categorical variables ",
          xlab = "continuous value",
                par.settings = ggplot2like())

  #y versus levels of B , grouped by a(color and line are defined by a)
  p2 <- dotplot(b~y, groups= a , 
          data = mydat,
          type = c("l"),
          main = "interaction between numeric and categorical variables ",
          xlab = "continuous value",
                par.settings = ggplot2like())

  library(gridExtra)           ## to arrange many grid plots
   grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer trailed off, but I'm guessing you would have said that the top plots show each level of A at various various levels of B? I know very little about lattice itself... is there a way to pull out the coordinates of a legend and then plot lines touching the legend using those coordinates? Thanks.